# How to reject pushing a super-project with a reference to a submodule that hasn't been pushed with Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am hosting a git super-project containing a number of submodules on Azure DevOps.  I'd like the server to reject any pushes to the super project that reference a commit in a submodule that hasn't been pushed.  This is important to catch the case where the submitter forgets to push the submodule and the submodule reference on the server can't be resolved by someone else.

I have seen git servers with filters for this, but since I'm using Azure Dev Ops, I'd like to figure out how to configure this on my super-projects in ADO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this feature exist in Azure DevOps.

You can find all the settings and policies for Azure Repo [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), your request doesn't exist there.

There is an [open Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365841/add-git-pre-receive-hooks.html) to add Git pre-receive hooks, the status is On Roadmap, maybe it could helps when it will be available.

You can also try to [create a new Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) regarding this.

Comment: Thanks - Upvoted answer.  Will accept it if I can't find a workaround.

Comment: Despite much searching and hand-wringing I am unable to find a solution. Accepting this answer until a solution is found.